# LDAP attribute is missing in ldap python result3 function result but comes in ldapsearch command result

Tags: python, ldap

We have python application which reads entries from ldap and updates the users in other database. Now the problem I got in to is, When I run

```
ldapsearch 'sAMAccountName=myID`
```

I am able to get attribute `employeeID` successfully.

But from python code I am not able to print `employeeID` attribute.

**My python code is as given below:**

```
import ldap
import datetime
conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://url:port')
conn.simple_bind_s('CN=ABC,OU=XYZ,OU=AAA,DC=users,DC=net', 'password')
from ldap.controls import SimplePagedResultsControl

LDAP_ATTRS = ['*']
LDAP_FILTER = (
        '(&(sAMAccountName=myId))'
)

pager = SimplePagedResultsControl(
            criticality=True,
            size=1500000,
            cookie=''
        )

msgid = conn.search_ext(
                'DC=users,DC=net', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                LDAP_FILTER.format(''),
                LDAP_ATTRS, serverctrls=[pager]
            )

rtype, rdata, rmsgid, serverctrls = conn.result3(msgid)

for dn, entry in rdata:
        for ent in entry:
            print(ent)
```

I have no clue why I am not able to print one of attribute (`employeeID`). Which comes by ldapsearch command.

**EDIT**

First I doubted at some assumption like user should have permission to read attribute. But I am not sure my assumption is correct.

As I am new to python and also ldap, I read about ldap schema and reading the result about result according to schema. It will be helpful if anyone explains their understanding so that it will help for analyzing and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `ldap3` instead of `ldap`.
https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/

This is because the sAMAccountName is an attribute of your entry.

Can you try this code ?

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE, ALL_ATTRIBUTES
import json

server = Server("ldap://url:port")
connection = Connection(server, "CN=ABC,OU=XYZ,OU=AAA,DC=users,DC=net", "password")
connection.search(
    "DC=users,DC=net",
    "(objectCategory=user)",
    search_scope=SUBTREE,
    attributes=ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
)
data = json.loads(connection.response_to_json())

entries = data["entries"]
for entry in entries:
    print(entry["attributes"])
    print(entry["attributes"]["sAMAccountName"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your code but still i am not able to find the attribute `employeeID` which comes in ldapsearch command from terminal.

Comment: If `sAMAccountName` wasn't an attribute of the entry he wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifically specifying "employeeID" in your attributes list (LDAP_ATTRS) instead of "*" in your search_ext call to see if that returns the employeeID?

Or try not specifying an attributes list as the documentation in https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.search
says "The retrieved attributes can be limited with the attrlist parameter. If attrlist is **None**, all the attributes of each entry are returned."

Comment: The first suggestion wouldn't make any difference unless `employeeID` is an operational entry. The second suggestion is no different from specifying `"*"`, again unless it's an operational entry. Which it isn't, as you can tell from the `ldapsearch` success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was employeeID was in different port and all other attributes are in different port. I don't know exactly how it was working for ldapsearch command but ldapsearch was able to get all attributes but not from python library because connection object i was getting is from different port where employeeID attribute is not present.

**Used [strace](https://strace.io/)** for finding ldapsearch trying which port to fetch all attributes.

Comment: That could mean you were talking to a different LDAP server.

Comment: @user207421 No ldap service will run on multiple port like 3268 3269 389 etc, My python code was using different port where employeeID attribute is not served. But strace for ldapsearch command helped me to identify employeeID is fetched from which port. SO i changed implementation to use that port

Comment: I was not knowing ldapsearch command internally referring to which port. As ldapsearch was able to get employeeID but not my python code. So i digged into ldapsearch command using strace and it helped me.